# wordpress add_rewrite_rule com campo personalizado

Tags: wordpress

Como eu faço para criar uma URL no WordPress, usando o `add_rewrite_rule`, igual abaixo mas filtrando os posts por um campo personalizado?

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^leaf/([0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?page_id=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa associação não existe nos argumentos padrão, mas você pode criar assim:

```
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
    // Crie uma rewrite tag junto à rewrite rule:
    add_rewrite_tag( '%campo_personalizado%', '([0-9]+)' );
    // Use essa tag na regra que vai criar:
    add_rewrite_rule('^leaf/([0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?campo_persoanlizado=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
```

Agora você pode filtrar a query pela busca:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'filtra_query' );
function filtra_query( $query ) {
    // Agora o campo personalizado está disponível para a query
    $campo = $query->get( 'campo_personalizado' );

    // E se ele existe fazemos uma meta_query para buscar
    // somente os posts com aquele valor:
    if ( ! empty( $campo ) ) {

        $args = array( array(
            'key' => 'campo_personalizado',
            'value' => $campo
            ) );

        $query->set( 'meta_query', $args );
    }
}
```